# Не работает изменение стиля метки

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Здравствуйте, не работает изменение стиля метки, а именно свойство preset

Мой код скопированный из документации: http://joxi.ru/zANpyB0IBMa6Nm

То что получилось: http://joxi.ru/MAj7Ge0t4bBxBr

Стиль метки не меняется, хотя все остальные опции работают.

Comment: Замените ссылки в вопросе на код, ссылки имеют свойство умирать и тогда вопрос потеряет свою пользу.

Comment: проверьте, версию API: в версии 2.1 пресеты называются иначе. В песочнице [есть пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark?from=SO)

Comment: Посмотри правильные названия пресетов
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/option.presetStorage-docpage/